# How to update mysql table with array of data - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to update multiple rows using this code:

```
$data = [];
foreach ($projectFieldOptions as $mapping) {
    $data[] = [
        'import_field_slug' => $mapping['value'],
        'internal_field_slug' => $mapping['text'],
        'custom_field'  => $mapping['custom'],
        'import'        => 1,
        'date_upd'      => $now,
    ];
}

$update_feed_mappings = DB::table($db_name . '.feed_mappings')
->where('id_project', $token)
->where('id_feed', $id_feed)
->update($data);
```

But I got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `shibbir_DB1`.`feed_mappings` set `0` = {\"import_field_slug\":\"date\",..........
```

Would you tell me how can I fix it?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  The current code doesn't make sense.  If `$projectFieldOptions` is an array of sets of data, which set do you want to update the DB with?  For example if `$projectFieldOptions` contains 2 elements, it means you have 2 values for `$mapping['value']` (and all the other `$mapping['...']` elements).  Which one of those `$mapping['value']` values do you want to update your DB records with?  Is the `update()` maybe supposed to be in the loop, with some qualifier so that a different set of records is updated each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update` only works for a single row and each key must correspond to a column in your sql table. You can't use if with a multi-dimensional array.

You should move your update inside your loop to fix the issue.

```
foreach ($projectFieldOptions as $mapping) {
    $data = [
        'import_field_slug' => $mapping['value'],
        'internal_field_slug' => $mapping['text'],
        'custom_field'  => $mapping['custom'],
        'import'        => 1,
       'date_upd'      => $now,
    ];

    DB::table($db_name . '.feed_mappings')
        ->where('id_project', $token)
        ->where('id_feed', $id_feed)
        ->update($data);
}
```

Comment: let me try with this

Comment: I can see that it's updating the same value to all rows. Its update last array values to all.

Comment: You need to change 'id_project' and 'id_feed' per iteration, they are always same

Comment: ooooooooooooooo, my bad...... :(

Answer (score 0):

Consider the code below please

```
$data = [];
$projectFieldOptions = 

$data[] = [
  'import_field_slug' => 1,
  'internal_field_slug' => 1,
  'custom_field'  => 1,
  'import'        => 1,
   'date_upd'      => 1,
];
    
$data[] = [
  'import_field_slug' => 2,
  'internal_field_slug' => 2,
  'custom_field'  => 2,
  'import'        => 2,
  'date_upd'      => 2,
];
    
var_dump($data);
```

The output will be

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["import_field_slug"]=>
    int(1)
    ["internal_field_slug"]=>
    int(1)
    ["custom_field"]=>
    int(1)
    ["import"]=>
    int(1)
    ["date_upd"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["import_field_slug"]=>
    int(2)
    ["internal_field_slug"]=>
    int(2)
    ["custom_field"]=>
    int(2)
    ["import"]=>
    int(2)
    ["date_upd"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

So your update translates into something like that

```
update(['0' => array(...))
```

But update method needs something like that

```
update(['import_field_slug' => 1,...])
```

Conclusion: please update each record one by one inside your loop

[Further reading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#updates)